# Rails connects to database without username or password

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm developing a web using Rails 4. Trying to configure the production environment I noticed that neither the username nor the password are needed. I have the following configuration under **database.yml**:

```
development:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: walko
  username: walko
  password:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  encoding: unicode
  database: <%= ENV['DB_NAME'] %>
  username:
  password:
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

I can realize migrations and connections to the production database from **rails console**.

How is this possible?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Rails uses the Ruby `Pg` gem, which uses PostgreSQL's `libpq` client library.

`libpq` uses the *current system user name* if no user name is supplied.

No password is required by the server if `peer`, `ident sameuser` or `trust` authentication is used in `pg_hba.conf`. If the server doesn't request a password, `libpq` doesn't try to send one and doesn't care if one is missing.

You can actually supply the empty string for the database too; `libpq` will then use the db that's the same as your username if it exists.

Comment: It worked for me! As you said, it was using my system credentials.